# Construction of sections of an algebra bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

A section of a locally trivial algebra bundle (E,p,B) is a continuous map $S$ from $p:B\to E$ such $p\circ S= ID$. For an ideal bundle $H$ of $E$, I am trying to construct sections of $E$ such that every element of $H_x$  is in some section of $E$.

I have listed my argument here.

Suppose my base space is compact Hausdorff. Then $B$ is a union of connected components and fibres are isomorphic on each component.Now for a particular $x\in B$, and $y \in H_x$ I set, $S(x)=y$ throughout the component containing $x$. On all other components I fix a particular element of the fibre. Then on each component S is continuous and by pasting lemma, S is a section of $E$.
This argument looks fine but still is not convincing to me. Can anyone help me to refine it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to apply pasting lemma. It is generally not true that functions defined on connected components can be glued to whole space. Otherwise any function defined on a totally disconnected space (e.g. Cantor set) would be continuous, which is true only for discrete spaces. Moreover, it is generally not true that global sections exist to begin with. Although I'm not 100% sure for the special case of algebra bundle. Also, by your construction $S$ is constant on components? That can't possibly satisfy $p\circ S=id$ condition.

Comment: Since my base space is compact Hausdorff, I can find a open cover and on each connected component fibres are isomorphic. Constant function is continuous on each component so that I can glue them together? Cantor set is closed and completely disconnected, so that we cannot use the pasting lemma? $p\circ S( x)$ is $x$ right?

Comment: No, you can't glue them. For a simple example consider $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ defined as $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Restriction of $f$ to any connected component is continuous, but $f$ is not. Being totally disconnected is not the real cause, it is just an example. The point is that pasting lemma doesn't work in the case when space has infinitely many connected components.

Comment: I get the pasting lemma part. But if $a$ and $b$ are two different points on a component, then there are two different fibres on $a$ and $b$, say $E_a$ and $E_b$ so that on $E_a$, we have  $p\circ S(a)=a$ and on $E_b$, $p\circ S(b)=b$. For example the zero section takes $0$ on each fibre.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the construction of $S$. I thought $y$ is fixed, but it is in different fibres, nevermind. Anyway your construction cannot possibly work. Because for some spaces, e.g. sphere, there are no non-vanishing sections (hairy ball theorem). And since sphere is connected, then your $S$ is non-zero in each fibre. That cannot work.

Comment: Here's an idea: you may be able to do the construction by first defining a local section and then extending it to global through a partition of unity. Assuming $E$ is paracompact. Something worth trying.

Comment: Thank you for the lead. I am trying to do it. Assuming my space is compact Hausdorff. Locally, on the closed subspace singleton $\{a\}$, I defined $S(a)=y$ on $E_a$. Using partition of unity, I can extend this section to entire of $E$. This will do?

Comment: Maybe. That's my idea, but I might be wrong. I didn't try it.

Comment: Thank you for the idea